# How to add multiple filter in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview

I have implement a search feature to my RecyclerView. but the list can be filtered while user press button to filter list by name, age or city.

here the code:

**this is adapter recyclerview**

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }
    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<List_Pemilih> filterdelist = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                filterdelist.addAll(Listfull);
            }else {
                String filterpatern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (List_Pemilih item: Listfull){
                    if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterpatern) || item.getAge().toLowerCase().contains(filterpatern) || item.getCity().toLowerCase().contains(filterpatern)){
                        filterdelist.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filterdelist;

            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            Listitempemilih.clear();

            Listitempemilih.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

and this code in my fragment:

```
        searchViewx.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Get Function filter from recyclerview adapter
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add another getFilter() method and return a new filter. The interface has to be implementet only once:

In the adapter class (implements Filterable):

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

//get second filter
public Filter getSecondFilter() {
    return mSecondFilter;
}

private Filter mFilter() = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        //do filtering
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //do something with the results
    }
}

private Filter mSecondFilter() = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        //do filtering with second filter
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //do something with the results
    }
}
```

To accecc the second filter, you have to call

```
adapter.getSecondFilter().filter(newText);
```

from your fragment or your activity.